# Is there another resource for Carter-Wegman-style message authentication?

Tags: hash, authentication, reference-request, carter-wegman

I'm wondering if there are other resources that cover Carter-Wegman style message authentication, besides the sources themselves.

Is there an online text or a book that covers their ideas?  I'd prefer something that's very thorough, and less importantly, free.  I'm just really trying to get a feel for their ideas and related works.

*Wikipedia covers VMAC, which is an application of their ideas, here:*
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMAC

**LINKS**

The original sources are linked through http://www.dblp.org/search/index.php#query=author:mark_n_wegman:&qp=H1.1000:W1.4:F1.4:F2.4:F3.4:F4.4

...and you can refine the search to just Wegman and Carter's works by clicking on Carter on the right side.

Comment: This should probably be migrated to Crypto.SE.

Comment: Are you looking for something from the theory perspective (e.g., how to design or analyze a universal hash function)?  Are you looking for something from the applied perspective (e.g., how to use Carter-Wegman hashing for message authentication in your application)?  The answers will be very different in these two cases.

Comment: @D.W.: I am slightly more interested in the theory, but I'm also very interested "the applied perspective" as well.  So Really anything that covers this topic is of interest to me.  I think that your reference to universal hashing in your answer may be a good place for me to start.

Comment: http://www.cs.ut.ee/~lipmaa/crypto/link/mac/ contains some source from authors you mentioned hope it may help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You didn't mention at what level you're hoping for, so I'll provide a few resources, and you can figure out which ones best meet your needs.

- [UMAC: Fast and secure message authentication](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/umac-full.pdf). John Black, Shai Halevi, Hugo Krawczyk, Ted Krovetz and Phillip Rogaway, CRYPTO 1999.  (This research paper describes UMAC, a fast Carter-Wegman style hash.  It also gives a lot of good background on the topic.)
- [Wikipedia's entry on UMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UMAC) gives some background on universal hashing and its relevance to message authentication.
- [On fast and provably secure message authentication based on universal hashing](http://www.shoup.net/papers/macs.pdf), Victor Shoup, CRYPTO 1996.  (This research paper gives some of the theory behind universal hashing.  It might be a tough slog if you are not a theoretician.)
- [Stronger security bounds for Wegman-Carter-Shoup authenticators](http://cr.yp.to/antiforgery/securitywcs-20050227.pdf). Dan Bernstein, EUROCRYPT 2005. (Even more of the theory behind universal hashing.  An even tougher slog, if you are not used to theoretical crypto, but good stuff if you are.)
- If you want to learn some of the crypto-theory, here are some resources:

  - You could start with [Chapter 7 of Bellare and Rogaway's lecture notes on modern cryptography](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/users/mihir/cse207/w-mac.pdf), which provides an introduction to message authentication from a theoretical perspective.  Read to the end of Section 7.4, then you can skip 7.5, 7.6, and 7.7, and jump straight to 7.8, which describes universal hashing -- but is unfortunately as yet incomplete.
  - You could read Katz and Lindell's [Introduction to Modern Cryptography](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/imc.html).  Start with Chapter 1, then Chapter 4 (particularly 4.1-4.4).  Unfortunately, while they have a good treatment of the theoretical foundations of message authentication, they don't cover universal hashing as a method of message authentication.

These days, Carter-Wegman-style message authentication is often mentioned under the name "universal hashing".  That search term may help you find a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

I found chapter 7 of the (still in progress) book "Graduate Course in Applied Cryptography" by Shoup and Boneh pretty useful as a thorough explanation of authentication based on universal hashing: https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/cryptobook/